# VS Code scroll-jump when scrolling after alt+tab on Linux

Tags: visual-studio-code

It intermittently happens than when I move back to the text editor window, either from another editor tab or from an external program, that when I just roll the mouse scroll wheel by one click, the window jumps to the bottom of the file, no matter where in the file the cursor is at that moment. It's only the window scroll that jumps, not the cursor. This happens maybe every 1/15 times when changing between tabs. Once I'm editing again after this glitch, everything behaves as normal.

It goes without saying that this is quite frustrating.

I'm hoping someone here knows how to fix this, or at least debug it. Is there a log recorded by VS Code so that I can look at the log when I notice the glitch happening again, or can I enable such a log?

System info:
Version: 1.58.0,
Commit: 2d23c42a936db1c7b3b06f918cde29561cc47cd6,
Date: 2021-07-08T06:53:55.113Z,
Electron: 12.0.13,
Chrome: 89.0.4389.128,
Node.js: 14.16.0,
V8: 8.9.255.25-electron.0,
OS: Linux x64 4.15.0-147-generic

Answer (score 5):

Known issue (since 2017), but unfortunately no known solution: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795

Answer (score 3):

There is a workaround to solve this isue:
https://github.com/lucasresck/gnome-shell-extension-alt-tab-scroll-workaround

Answer (score 2):

#### Cause

I'm going to wager a guess that this is [Editor: scroll jumps randomly (related to Chrome, Electron, xinput) #28795](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795). There's some elaboration on the cause in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/28795#issuecomment-1518237312):

> This is caused by a missing or broken workaround for an X11/XInput 2.1 protocol design issue https://who-t.blogspot.com/2012/06/xi-21-protocol-design-issues.html [...] 'm now seeing this with Fedora 37 (using Xorg, not Wayland) but not on Fedora 35 or Ubuntu 20.04 (also Xorg) so it is possible for this to work "correctly" under the right conditions (as of VSCodium 1.77.3).

Also apparently related is https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=608246 and https://issues.chromium.org/issues/41251816#comment79.

#### Solutions / Workarounds

- Some workarounds are listed in the issue thread's opening comment:

  > - imwheel - not suitable for all users
  > - wayland - not suitable for all users

  Some users find that imwheel works well for them, and others report that it doesn't, or that it introduces other problems. Your mileage may vary.
- Since apparently this only happens when you use <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, you can work around the issue by switching between applications using other means, such as the mouse pointer, or other keyboard shortcuts like <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd><number></kbd>
- [lucasresck](/u/12724988) wrote a GNOME extension that apparently fixes the issue (the workarounds didn't work for them): https://extensions.gnome.org/extension/5282/alttab-scroll-workaround/ <sup><sub>(I have no affiliation with this extension)</sub></sup>.

---

See also [How to solve a scrolling misbehavior after doing Alt+Tab?](https://askubuntu.com/q/1075621/1624654)

Answer (score 1):

imwheel solved this issue for me

`imwheel` is a utility for Linux systems, including Ubuntu, designed to enhance and customize mouse wheel behavior, particularly for adjusting the scroll speed and mapping mouse wheel input to keyboard input. It's particularly useful when the default system settings do not provide the necessary options to adjust the mouse wheel's behavior to the user's preference.

#### Installation

To install `imwheel` on Ubuntu, you can use the following command in the terminal:

```bash
sudo apt install imwheel
```

This command installs `imwheel` from the official Ubuntu repositories.

#### Configuration

After installing `imwheel`, you need to create a configuration file named `.imwheelrc` in your home directory to specify your preferences for the mouse wheel behavior. You can use a text editor to create and edit this file. Here's an example of how to set it up:

1. Open a terminal and run:

```bash
gedit ~/.imwheelrc
```

2. Paste the following configuration into the file:

```
".*"
None, Up, Button4, 3
None, Down, Button5, 3
Control_L, Up, Control_LButton4
Control_L, Down, Control_LButton5
Shift_L, Up, Shift_LButton4
Shift_L, Down, Shift_LButton5
```

The numbers `3` at the end of the `Button4` and `Button5` lines represent the scroll speed. You can adjust these numbers to increase or decrease the scroll speed according to your preference.

#### Running `imwheel`

To apply the settings and start `imwheel`, use the following command in the terminal:

```bash
imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"
```

The `--kill` option ensures that any previous instances of `imwheel` are terminated before starting a new one, and `--buttons "4 5"` specifies that only the scroll wheel (buttons 4 and 5) are affected, allowing other mouse buttons to function normally[9].

#### Making `imwheel` Start Automatically

To ensure `imwheel` starts automatically with your system, you can add it to your startup applications. This process may vary depending on your desktop environment, but generally, you can find an option to add startup applications in the system settings or control center. Use the command `imwheel --kill --buttons "4 5"` as the command to run at startup.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).