# VS Code will backspace or indent-backwards whenever I alt+tab to another program and alt+tab back

Tags: visual-studio-code, formatting, cursor, indentation

So currently whenever I'm looking at something on a browser or another program, and I'm simultaneously typing in VS code, when I alt tab out of VS Code to the program, and then alt tab back, vs code doesn't keep the position my insertion point cursor at the same location, but will back space to the last word, or if there's no word in that line, it'll back space all the way to the last empty line.

For example, if I have:

1)const express = require()
2)
3) // creates the express app
4) const app = express();
5)
6)     | <-- cursor

and my cursor is at that line 6 when I alt tab out, then when I go back to vs code, the cursor has moved all the way to the beginning of line 5 by itself instead of staying indented in line 6:

1)const express = require()
2)
3) // creates the express app
4) const app = express();
5) | <-- cursor
6)

I never had this issue before until recently and I didn't change anything except install SQlite Viewer but I have tried uninstalling that and it didn't affect anything.

I couldn't find anything on vscode settings about it.

I have auto save set to afterDelay and 'Format on Save'.

The only extensions I have installed in VS Code are Code Runner, Live Server, and SQLite Viewer.

Comment: Welcome! Please copy and paste the output of the `Help: About` command (run in [the command palette](//code.visualstudio.com/docs/getstarted/userinterface#_command-palette)) **into your question post**. see also https://stackoverflow.com/a/77831268/11107541